# JSF lifecycle process validation phase

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2, lifecycle

I wrote a simple JSF-application with two validators to understand JSF process-validation phase. Here're the validators:

```
@FacesValidator("second")
public class AnotherValidator implements Validator{
    public void validate(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object arg2)
            throws ValidatorException {
        System.out.println("Validation phase, the second");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
        throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("The second"));
    }
}
```

and

```
@FacesValidator("first")
public class ProducerValidator implements Validator{
    public void validate(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object arg2)
            throws ValidatorException {
        System.out.println("Validation phase, the first");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
        throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("The first"));
    }
}
```

I thought that if we call the `renderResponse` method from a `validate` method, the JSF-implementation should skip to the Render response phase. But actually I have the following console output:

```
Validation phase, the first
Validation phase, the second
```

In spite of calling `renderResponse` from the first validator, the second validator was being invoked anyway... Why? Facelets markup:

```
<h:inputText value="#{helloBean.p}" converter="conv">
    <f:validator validatorId="first"/>
    <f:validator validatorId="second" />
</h:inputText>
```

Comment: @Tiny To me it seems to be more clear to post validation messages for a specific component through the `facesContext.addMessage(String, FacesMessage)` and use `<h:messages for="id" />`...

Comment: @Tiny BTW, I'm trying to avoid using `<h:messages />` without specifying component id or `globalOnly`, is'n that true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is specified behavior. From the [`FacesContext#renderResponse()` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#renderResponse--):

> Signal the JavaServer faces implementation that, as soon **as the current phase of the request processing lifecycle has been completed**, control should be passed to the Render Response phase, bypassing any phases that have not been executed yet.

So, it doesn't abruptly abort the current phase as you expected. It will finish the current phase and then advance to the render response phase.

Only, it does that already by default when you throw a `ValidatorException` from inside a validator. So, doing it both is unnecessary.

Comment: I just thought that if I want to post a validation error message for a specific component, is it acceptable to do the following in the validate meathod: `facesContext.addMessage(component.getId(), new FacesMessage("Validation error")); facesContext.renderResponse();` So, if some validator failed we perform the rest of the validation and then skip to the Render Response phase without updating invoke application and updating data model phases. To me, it looks perfectly fine, but maybe I lost something...?

Comment: Uhmmm isn't that what BalusC wrote: The behaviour you want is the behaviour you get as in the example, but without the need to call the `facesContext.renderResponse()`... or do *I* miss something?

Comment: Don't manually add a faces message in a validator, just throw it along with validator exception. You don't need to manually call `FacesContext#renderResponse()`, JSF will already implicitly do that when conversion or validation fails.